# Sorting a ruby hash with underscore in keys

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

I usually sort ruby hashes using the very famous `sort` method as given in my example below. But this terribly fails when the string key has an underscore in it. For eg:

```
h = {"b" => 1, "a" => 2}
Hash[h.sort]
```

sorts the hash perfectly. But when the hash is something like

```
h = {"b_d" => 1, "a_v" => 2}
```

I do not get the desired sort order. The point to note here is `h.sort` sorts the hash and produces an `Enumerable` object. But when I convert the object back to Hash using `Hash[h.sort]`, it loses the order here. Any suggestions for a better process could be helpful.

**Note:** I'm using `Ruby 1.8.7`, so an `OrderedHash` is not much in my lenses.

Comment: What's the difference? Why are you sorting it?

Comment: To sign an OAuth request where the params string should be ordered.

Comment: Your assertion that the first example "sorts the hash perfectly" is likely to be coincidence. If you only have 2 keys it's a 50% chance that any pseudo-random ordering will be "correct"

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.8.7, as soon as you convert back to a `Hash` you necessarily lose your ordering. You'll have to get rid of the vanilla `Hash` to get this to work - maybe try keeping the `Enumerable` you get back from `sort` and using that for as long as possible?